# PyQT, Drag&Drop: Disable copy, only allow move

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop, pyqt

I would like to create 2 QListWidget (let's call them "A" and "B") with the following Drag&Drop behaviour:

- Entries can be copied from "A" to "B"
- Entries can NOT be moved from "A" to "B"
- Entries can NOT be moved OR copied from "B" to "A"

The last point is not the problem, but I couldn't find a way yet to disable the move action while allowing copying from "A" to "B".

Can someone point me where to look?

Thanks.

Comment: I assume you still need to move items *within* "A".

Comment: No, no moving inside list "A". Maybe sorting but I think this has nothing to do with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to solve my problem:

```python
class ListB(QtGui.QListWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(ListB, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

    def supportedDropActions(self):
        return QtCore.Qt.CopyAction
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to set mimeData to an exclusive value (maybe something like "myapplication/somewidget-somefeature") see [`dragEnterEvent` in the draggable example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-draganddrop-draggabletext-dragwidget-cpp.html) to see how to accept/reject a drag.

See `dropEvent` on that same example on *how* to set mimeData

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to move items *within* list "A", the solution is simple:

```
    self.listA.setDragEnabled(True)
    self.listB.setAcceptDrops(True)
```

Comment: This doesn't solve point 2 for me. I Can still switch from `copy` to `move` by pressing the command key.